# Which History SQL Lite DB Does Selenium Use When Launching Chrome?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

When using selenium to launch chrome which SQL Lite db is used?  Under normal usage the History sql lite db is used here `C:\Users\[USER]\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\History`; however, when selenium launches chrome its not using/updating that History file. The following capabilties user-data-dir and databaseEnabled have been provided, but haven't solved the problem.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

the user profile path was one level too deep. Fixing the path on windows to stop at `C:/Users/[USER]/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data"` resolve the issue.